# Java String Wrapping:How do I wrap words in a String at New line character(\n)

Tags: java, regex, string, conditional-statements, newline

We want to wrap the word in a string at New Line character(\n).Basically, We are pressing  ENTER to start a new line.

that is  Enter key to create a new line in Our message when pressed.

**Input data :**

String is captured in comment column.
Comment column  given is:

```
EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS\nC3 Generic\nLOC 0833\nExpected arrival 01/07/2016\nOTYPE NE\nTRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321
```

**We tried on it:**

```
string s = "EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS C3 Generic LOC 0833 Expected arrival 01/07/2016  OTYPE NE TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321"  ;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 20)) != -1) {
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}
```

Expected data  after transformation:
linebreak is new line character

```
Long  String of Comment field  should Splits in 6 different lines 

EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS

C3 Generic

LOC 0833

Expected arrival 01/07/2016

OTYPE NE

TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321
```

**Exact data after output look like :**

```
SalesOrder    NComment                            SalesOrderLine                    StockCode
183590  EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS                         1                                 
183590                                                  2                         abc-defg-13OZ-24              
183590  C3    Generic                                   37                                
183590  LOC 0833                                        38                                
183590  Expected arrival               01/07/2016       39                                
183590  OTYPE NE                                        40                                
183590  TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321                51
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated !

Comment: What is the splitting criteria ? It can not be " " because this char also exist in a middle of "LOC 0833" as an example.

Comment: Splitting at  new line(\n) width character. and max width  length is 20.

Comment: If "\n" is not is s it can not be used as splitting criteria, So it has to be a certain length (or lengths) , or another char.

Comment: We want to implement this java code :http://paste.ofcode.org/S4LEQM2RpEcre3PcYnbpxC  if possible we would like to replace each line space with \n.

Comment: Your 6 line output is not possible...

Comment: Here line break as new line character ON PRESSING OF ENTER KEY

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't really get what you want to achieve. Do you want to insert the break BEFORE the word which passes the 20th character?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    int currentSpaceFound = sb.indexOf(" ");
    int i = 1;
    while (currentSpaceFound != -1) {
        int lastOccurence = currentSpaceFound;
        currentSpaceFound = sb.indexOf(" ", currentSpaceFound + 1);
        if (currentSpaceFound > (20 * i)) {
            sb.setCharAt(lastOccurence, '\n');
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Yes we want to insert breakIterator before the word which passes through 20 th character.output should be  splitted into  6 different lines  as mentioned in example.

Comment: We would like to implement  this program of java :http://paste.ofcode.org/S4LEQM2RpEcre3PcYnbpxC

Comment: you mean content of 6 th line is wrong : it is  upto the mark. or correct me if i am wrong in interpreting this.

Comment: But your six-line-solution is wrong, isn't it? for instance, EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS has 24 chars and should break after EDI ORDER-SAVE?

Comment: first line should be  EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS

Comment: can we go for max width 30?

Comment: We have line break as  at new line character .  Then possible to 6 split of lines for ex :  aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\nee\nff

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
private String wrapComment(String comment, int length) {

    if(comment.length() <= length) return comment;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(comment);

    int spaceIndex = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < comment.length(); i ++) {

        if(i % length == 0 && spaceIndex > -1) {
            stringBuilder.replace(spaceIndex, spaceIndex+1, "\n");
            spaceIndex = -1;
        }

        if(comment.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            spaceIndex = i;
        }

        stringBuilder.append(comment.charAt(i));
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Testing:

```
String comment = "EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS C3 Generic LOC 0833 Expected arrival 01/07/2016  OTYPE NE TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321";
System.out.println(wrapComment(comment, 30));
```

Output:

```
EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS C3
Generic LOC 0833 Expected
arrival 01/07/2016  OTYPE NE TRKPC
01 GM/00007643020008361321
```

Comment: Yes it looks approximate . But i have  given  expected data output. it will give 6 lines only.

Comment: We want to implement  something like this word wrap:paste.ofcode.org/S4LEQM2RpEcre3PcYnbpxC if possible we would like to replace each line space with \n

Comment: You mean you want another newline after each line?

Comment: i wanted to  say when this long string splits it should save like this in sql database . http://paste.ofcode.org/KbgzFqYqUUaSGpTQFgarWh in 6 new lines exactly.

Comment: We have line break as at new line character . Then possible to 6 split of lines for ex : aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\nee\nff